# How can I send traces directly to webservice without using opentelemtry collector using oltp exporter in http protocol?

Tags: grpc-go, exporter, open-telemetry

I am trying to send 2 different microservice data to my web service using open telemetry-javaagent ,one with jaeger exporter and the other with otlp, it looks like all the traces of jaeger are sent successfully and otlp are dropped as my web service only support HTTP protocol And javaagent has otlp grpc exporter.
I am not able to find any other agent which would exporter data using otlp in HTTP format.
are there any references through which I can get such an agent

Comment: i am looking for the same thing.  OLTP Http Exporter for java.

Comment: there is no otlp http exporter directly from agent,you will have to use hotel collector always in order to get traces